# How to fix javascript elapsed time issue in my code

Tags: javascript

I want to create a javascript that counts if you're IDLE for 5 minutes, it then gives you IDLE status = true and starts counting the rest of time that you're idle, until you reset the timer by moving your mouse

My issue is that I don't know how to count both the time elapsed till it reaches 5 minutes and also the rest of the time until the time resets again

I have tried to use a timeout to activate the isInactive() function, but then, I didn't found how can I add those 5 minutes elapsed for this function to start + the rest of time the user has been idle and alert the whole time

I'm too new to javascript and I think I'm making a mistake on how and where I declare my variables

```
var inOffice = true;



function idleUser() {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var idleTime = (new Date().getTime() - start) / 1000;
    window.onload = resetTimer;
    window.onmousemove = resetTimer;
    window.onmousedown = resetTimer;  // catches touchscreen presses as well
    window.ontouchstart = resetTimer; // catches touchscreen swipes as well
    window.onclick = resetTimer;      // catches touchpad clicks as well
    window.onkeypress = resetTimer;

    function isInactive() {
        console.log("You are not active");
        inOffice = false;
        if(idleTime) {
            alert("You've been active for " + idleTIme;
        }
    }

    function resetTimer() {
        clearTimeout(time);
        time = setTimeout(isInactive, 5000)
    }
}

idleUser();
```

Comment: You need hoist your settimeout `time` before cleartimeout ..

Answer (score 0):

You `time` variable wasn't declared properly:

```js
var inOffice = true;



function idleUser() {
  var time;
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var idleTime = (new Date().getTime() - start) / 1000;
    window.onload = resetTimer;
    window.onmousemove = resetTimer;
    window.onmousedown = resetTimer;  // catches touchscreen presses as well
    window.ontouchstart = resetTimer; // catches touchscreen swipes as well
    window.onclick = resetTimer;      // catches touchpad clicks as well
    window.onkeypress = resetTimer;
    function isInactive() {
        console.log("You are not active");
        inOffice = false;
        if(idleTime) {
            alert("You've been active for " + idleTIme);
        }
    }

    function resetTimer() {
        clearTimeout(time);
        time = setTimeout(isInactive, 1000)
    }
}

idleUser();
```

Comment: Still not helping me too much on how to counter the extra time elapsed after the isInactive function starts

Answer (score 0):

I try to check your code for your issue.
I think to fix your issue you can change this code as following.

```
function idleUser() {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    console.log("You are not active");
    var time = setTimeout(isInactive, 5000)
    window.onload = resetTimer();
    window.onmousemove = resetTimer();
    window.onmousedown = resetTimer();  // catches touchscreen presses as well
    window.ontouchstart = resetTimer(); // catches touchscreen swipes as well
    window.onclick = resetTimer();      // catches touchpad clicks as well
    window.onkeypress = resetTimer();

    function isInactive() {
        console.log("You are not active");
        var idleTime = (new Date().getTime() - start) / 1000;
        console.log(idleTime);
        inOffice = false;
        if(idleTime) {
            alert("You've been active for " + idleTime);
        }
    }

    function resetTimer() {
        clearTimeout(time);
        time = setTimeout(isInactive, 5000);
    }
}
idleUser();
```

But this does not work with loop action.
In order to do you remove "ClearTimeout" function in "resetTimer" I think.